# Error Number:141,State:1,Class:15 A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a function to get count of appointments with matching doctorId,
 here is function :

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetSumOfAppointments (@doctorId int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @count int;
  SET @count = (SELECT
    COUNT(*)
  FROM dbo.Appointments
  WHERE DoctorId = @doctorId);
  RETURN ISNULL(@count, 0)
END
```

but its giving me error :

> Error Number:141,State:1,Class:15 A SELECT statement that assigns a
>   value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval
>   operations.

what exactly is the problem with above?

Comment: `SELECT @count=COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Appointments WHERE DoctorId = @doctorId`

Comment: I would accept @NewUser 's answer rather than mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetSumOfAppointments (@doctorId int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @count int;

  select @count = COUNT(*)
  FROM dbo.Appointments
  WHERE DoctorId = @doctorId;

  RETURN ISNULL(@count, 0)
END
```

Comment: Thanks Mitch Wheat ! :)

Answer (score 2):

No need to declare a variable and applying Isnull function since count(*) always returns number of records in that table suppose if the table is empty then you would get zero. Try like this make it simple.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetSumOfAppointments (@doctorId INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM dbo.Appointments
            WHERE DoctorId = @doctorId
            );
END
```

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: Thanks for voting up. I appreciate your quick response.